# jquery sortable combine two lists line

Tags: jquery, list, line, connect, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to be able to visually combine items in two seperate list by a line to represent that they are connected. Is this possible with jquery or with some other way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [jquery UI Sortable connected list](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists)

Comment: Instead of dragging 1 item from 1 list to another I would like to leave the items in their respective lists and just visually indicate they are connected by a line or something. Does that make sense?

Comment: `just visually indicate they are connected by a line or something.` Not sure what that means. Do you mean like having one list on the left and one list on the right? And have an arrow point from the end of left list to the beginning of the right list?

Comment: exactly, like: item1 <-----> item2